# User feed missing stories

Tags: facebook

Been slowly developing an Android app, and I noticed that the stories showing up in my app didn't match what I was seeing on the website.

I went into the Graph API explorer and started fooling around, and noticed that if I did something like

```
/john.doe/feed
```

I would not get back all the stories that I could see on the users profile on the website. This included plaintext posts like "I ate breakfast", but I'll get others. It seems the most recent ones are missing.

What am I missing? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: You need a valid Access Token from the user with read_stream permission to read his/her feeds.

Comment: I have a valid Access Token; I see this issue when using Graph Explorer on the Facebook Developer website. I get some user stories, but not all.